# How can I store mixins inside a Sass map for global variables in a theme?

Tags: sass, node-sass

I am trying to store mixins inside a Sass map that contains global variables for a theme. Then, use these mixins inside the styles of my components. But apparently, Sass doesn't support that...

Hi, guys!

I am developing a framework for building simple HTML pages with React and Sass. It's for some projects in the company I currently working.

I am trying to use Sass to create theme objects (maps) to store global variables. The framework will have different themes for different school subjects (it's for an educational project). When using the framework, the developer will have to specify what is the subject of the page in a JSON and I'll use this name to select the corresponding theme. To select the theme, I am using a function called `select-theme`.

Here is the implementation of this function.

```scss
$themes: (
  geography: geography.$theme,
  // other subject themes...
);

@function select-theme($theme) {
  @return map-get($themes, $theme);
}
```

Here is the theme map structure:

```scss
@import '../abstract/breakpoints';
@import '../abstract/colors';
@import '../abstract/typography';
@import '../abstract/radius';
@import '../abstract/spacing';

$theme: (
  breakpoints: (
    xs: $xs,
    sm: $sm,
    sml: $sml,
    md: $md,
    lg: $lg,
    xl: $xl,
    xll: $xll,
  ),
  colors: (
    background: (
      default: (
        color: $background-default,
        contrast-text: $background-default-contrast-text
      ),
      overlay: (
        color: $modal-overlay,
        contrast-text: $modal-overlay-contrast-text
      )
    ),
    accent: (
      900: (
        color: $accent-color-900,
        contrast-text: $accent-color-contrast-text-900
      ),
      800: (
        color: $accent-color-800,
        contrast-text: $accent-color-contrast-text-800
      ),
      700: (
        color: $accent-color-700,
        contrast-text: $accent-color-contrast-text-700
      ),
      600: (
        color: $accent-color-600,
        contrast-text: $accent-color-contrast-text-600
      ),
      500: (
        color: $accent-color-500,
        contrast-text: $accent-color-contrast-text-500
      ),
      400: (
        color: $accent-color-400,
        contrast-text: $accent-color-contrast-text-400
      ),
      300: (
        color: $accent-color-300,
        contrast-text: $accent-color-contrast-text-300
      ),
      200: (
        color: $accent-color-200,
        contrast-text: $accent-color-contrast-text-200
      ),
      100: (
        color: $accent-color-100,
        contrast-text: $accent-color-contrast-text-100
      )
    ),
    primary: (
      900: (
        color: $primary-color-900,
        contrast-text: $primary-color-contrast-text-900
      ),
      800: (
        color: $primary-color-800,
        contrast-text: $primary-color-contrast-text-800
      ),
      700: (
        color: $primary-color-700,
        contrast-text: $primary-color-contrast-text-700
      ),
      600: (
        color: $primary-color-600,
        contrast-text: $primary-color-contrast-text-600
      ),
      500: (
        color: $primary-color-500,
        contrast-text: $primary-color-contrast-text-500
      ),
      400: (
        color: $primary-color-400,
        contrast-text: $primary-color-contrast-text-400
      ),
      300: (
        color: $primary-color-300,
        contrast-text: $primary-color-contrast-text-300
      ),
      200: (
        color: $primary-color-200,
        contrast-text: $primary-color-contrast-text-200
      ),
      100: (
        color: $primary-color-100,
        contrast-text: $primary-color-contrast-text-100
      )
    ),
    // other colors...
    )
  ),
  typography: (
    main-heading: main-heading,
    heading: heading,
    body: body,
    footer: footer,
  ),
  radius: (
    primary: $primary-radius,
    secondary: $secondary-radius,
  ),
  spacing: (
    primary: $primary-spacing,
  )
)
```

The issue is that I am trying to store mixins inside this map. The values in the nested map `typography` are all mixins:

```scss
@import '../abstract/colors';

@mixin main-heading($font-color) {
  color: $font-color;
  font-family: "Dosis", sans-serif, arial;
  font-size: 6rem;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-align: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

@mixin heading($text-alinment: left, $font-color: $accent-color-500) {
  color: $font-color;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif, arial;
  font-size: 2.1rem;
  font-weight: 900;
  line-height: 2.8rem;
  margin-bottom: 0.7rem;
  text-align: $text-alinment;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

@mixin body($text-alinment: left, $font-color: $background-default-contrast-text) {
  color: $font-color;
  font-family: "Dosis", sans-serif, arial;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  line-height: 2.1rem;
  text-align: $text-alinment;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

@mixin footer($text-alinment: left, $font-color: $background-default-contrast-text) {
  color: $font-color;
  font-family: "Dosis", sans-serif, arial;
  font-size: 0.7rem;
  line-height: 2.1rem;
  text-align: $text-alinment;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

But, apparently, it's not possible to store mixins inside a map. When I try to the maps, I am getting this error:

```bash
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Undefined mixin.
   ╷
71 │       @include map-get($typography, 'heading');
   │       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
  src/components/Card/partials/Modal/style.scss 71:7  root stylesheet
```

Here is the piece of code that is giving me this error:

```scss
@import  '../../../../design-system/select-theme';

$theme: select-theme("geography");
$typography: map-get($theme, 'typography');

.Modal {
   // ...

  .content {
    // ...
  
    .title {
      @include map-get($typography, 'heading');
    }

    // ...
  }
}
```

Does anyone know what is the best approach to get the result I need?

Thanks